# Trying to enable scrolling via “overflow: scroll” in CSS

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to enable the `overflow: scroll` property as the content keeps overflowing, but the scroll bar doesn’t work at all. How to fix this? Is there any other way to make sure the content can be seen on the screen?

```css
#pageback {
    background-color: #00003D;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#pagewrap {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000099;
    width: 87.5%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
h1,
h2 {
    color: white;
}
p {
    color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageback">
    <h1>PageBackground</h1>
    <div id="pagewrap">
        <h2>Pagewrap</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum nisi, iaculis vitae dolor eget, fermentum convallis mauris. Nulla justo nunc, porttitor vitae posuere vel, vulputate at tortor. Maecenas ut bibendum tortor. Donec convallis, purus nec vulputate tempor, tortor lorem condimentum tellus, nec luctus leo lectus id mauris. Praesent convallis non tortor vel mattis. Curabitur sodales semper nulla. Fusce posuere tristique dui, id sodales enim malesuada id. Donec auctor ipsum nec pulvinar tincidunt. Donec sit amet leo vitae dui semper scelerisque. Praesent eleifend sit amet orci eget consectetur.</p>
        <p>Quisque ac felis nulla. Morbi nec lacus iaculis, pulvinar sem non, venenatis urna. Pellentesque molestie urna eu sem pellentesque, vitae sollicitudin ipsum aliquam. Morbi finibus, urna ut venenatis feugiat, risus nisi fringilla libero, quis rhoncus libero lacus quis nisl. Morbi sagittis viverra sapien at eleifend. Nam et mattis nibh. Phasellus lobortis posuere rutrum. Morbi at accumsan urna. Donec vehicula a sapien eu pretium. In scelerisque ut mi ac mollis. Aliquam bibendum sem justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ac enim erat.</p>
        <p>Fusce sit amet accumsan neque, cursus sagittis dolor. Vestibulum venenatis sapien sem, mollis sagittis neque pharetra sit amet. Morbi hendrerit arcu purus, et auctor ex porttitor at. Morbi ut pellentesque arcu. Integer efficitur tortor non eros posuere ultricies. Sed sollicitudin imperdiet libero id euismod. Morbi lobortis feugiat diam, in dignissim purus congue vel. Donec consectetur, leo quis imperdiet maximus, dui arcu gravida lectus, quis vehicula ipsum ipsum vitae mauris. Vivamus magna ante, dapibus ut tincidunt ut, tempor a felis. Pellentesque elit velit, venenatis eget lobortis pretium, pulvinar eu magna.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque pretium rutrum lobortis. Aliquam odio arcu, elementum eu turpis sit amet, rutrum ultrices sem. Maecenas eget efficitur dolor, vitae suscipit turpis. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus pellentesque velit sit amet nisl tincidunt, sit amet gravida est maximus. Fusce diam eros, tincidunt quis lacus quis, placerat luctus enim. Cras et ultrices est, eget gravida turpis. Curabitur tempus diam nec volutpat bibendum. In finibus arcu ut purus congue ultricies. Duis laoreet enim metus, sed malesuada odio scelerisque in. Donec pulvinar gravida finibus. Nunc eget lacus at lorem aliquet tristique a blandit orci.</p>
        <p>Praesent a lacinia dolor. Pellentesque sagittis fermentum tincidunt. Vivamus volutpat tincidunt nulla non commodo. Donec non mi ultrices, aliquet nibh at, varius lectus. Ut malesuada feugiat arcu at rutrum. Nam rhoncus leo efficitur sodales blandit. Pellentesque laoreet nulla nec nunc volutpat commodo nec vitae ipsum. Quisque nec commodo magna. Morbi ut blandit urna. Integer eros quam, porta dapibus porttitor vitae, mollis et diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec ac ornare tellus. Aenean commodo vitae turpis et tincidunt. In felis lectus, tristique in volutpat non, tristique non metus. Vivamus quis turpis mattis, venenatis nisl nec, varius nisi.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum nisi, iaculis vitae dolor eget, fermentum convallis mauris. Nulla justo nunc, porttitor vitae posuere vel, vulputate at tortor. Maecenas ut bibendum tortor. Donec convallis, purus nec vulputate tempor, tortor lorem condimentum tellus, nec luctus leo lectus id mauris. Praesent convallis non tortor vel mattis. Curabitur sodales semper nulla. Fusce posuere tristique dui, id sodales enim malesuada id. Donec auctor ipsum nec pulvinar tincidunt. Donec sit amet leo vitae dui semper scelerisque. Praesent eleifend sit amet orci eget consectetur.</p>
        <p>Quisque ac felis nulla. Morbi nec lacus iaculis, pulvinar sem non, venenatis urna. Pellentesque molestie urna eu sem pellentesque, vitae sollicitudin ipsum aliquam. Morbi finibus, urna ut venenatis feugiat, risus nisi fringilla libero, quis rhoncus libero lacus quis nisl. Morbi sagittis viverra sapien at eleifend. Nam et mattis nibh. Phasellus lobortis posuere rutrum. Morbi at accumsan urna. Donec vehicula a sapien eu pretium. In scelerisque ut mi ac mollis. Aliquam bibendum sem justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ac enim erat.</p>
        <p>Fusce sit amet accumsan neque, cursus sagittis dolor. Vestibulum venenatis sapien sem, mollis sagittis neque pharetra sit amet. Morbi hendrerit arcu purus, et auctor ex porttitor at. Morbi ut pellentesque arcu. Integer efficitur tortor non eros posuere ultricies. Sed sollicitudin imperdiet libero id euismod. Morbi lobortis feugiat diam, in dignissim purus congue vel. Donec consectetur, leo quis imperdiet maximus, dui arcu gravida lectus, quis vehicula ipsum ipsum vitae mauris. Vivamus magna ante, dapibus ut tincidunt ut, tempor a felis. Pellentesque elit velit, venenatis eget lobortis pretium, pulvinar eu magna.</p>
        <p>Pellentesque pretium rutrum lobortis. Aliquam odio arcu, elementum eu turpis sit amet, rutrum ultrices sem. Maecenas eget efficitur dolor, vitae suscipit turpis. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus pellentesque velit sit amet nisl tincidunt, sit amet gravida est maximus. Fusce diam eros, tincidunt quis lacus quis, placerat luctus enim. Cras et ultrices est, eget gravida turpis. Curabitur tempus diam nec volutpat bibendum. In finibus arcu ut purus congue ultricies. Duis laoreet enim metus, sed malesuada odio scelerisque in. Donec pulvinar gravida finibus. Nunc eget lacus at lorem aliquet tristique a blandit orci.</p>
        <p>Praesent a lacinia dolor. Pellentesque sagittis fermentum tincidunt. Vivamus volutpat tincidunt nulla non commodo. Donec non mi ultrices, aliquet nibh at, varius lectus. Ut malesuada feugiat arcu at rutrum. Nam rhoncus leo efficitur sodales blandit. Pellentesque laoreet nulla nec nunc volutpat commodo nec vitae ipsum. Quisque nec commodo magna. Morbi ut blandit urna. Integer eros quam, porta dapibus porttitor vitae, mollis et diam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec ac ornare tellus. Aenean commodo vitae turpis et tincidunt. In felis lectus, tristique in volutpat non, tristique non metus. Vivamus quis turpis mattis, venenatis nisl nec, varius nisi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYgNbN?editors=110)

Comment: Remove the `position:fixed` from the parent div would be a start. It's not really clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would suggest adding the code in the question itself (using the code syntax suggested in the editor)

Comment: @Paulie_D Well that removed the scroll problem, which I thank you for, but how do I make the background div remove the white border?

Comment: just specify the height it'll work for example set height:100px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS

```css
#pageback {
    background-color: #00003D;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; /* changed */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#pagewrap {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #000099;
    width: 87.5%;
    height: inherit; /* changed */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: scroll;
}
h1,
h2 {
    color: white;
}
p {
    color: silver;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raPbYd)